# Safe usage of glMapBufferRange() on Android/Java

Tags: java, android, opengl-es, opengl-es-3.0

I have working code using `glMapBufferRange()` from OpenGL-ES 3.0 on Android that looks like this:

```
  glBindBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, myVertexBufferName);
  glBufferData(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER, myVertexBufferSize, null, GL_STATIC_DRAW);
  ByteBuffer mappedBuffer = (ByteBuffer)glMapBufferRange(
    GL_ARRAY_BUFFER,
    0, myVertexBufferSize,
    GL_MAP_WRITE_BIT | GL_MAP_INVALIDATE_BUFFER_BIT);

  // [fill buffer...]

  glUnmapBuffer(GL_ARRAY_BUFFER);
```

My question is about downcasting the result of `glMapBufferRange()` to `ByteBuffer` on the third line. `glMapBufferRange()` is [declared to return a `Buffer`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/opengl/GLES30.html#glMapBufferRange(int,%20int,%20int,%20int)):

> `public static Buffer glMapBufferRange (int target, int offset, int length, int access)`

On my test platform the function returns a subclass of `ByteBuffer` so the cast works, but making this assumption for all platforms or Android versions supporting OpenGL-ES 3+ doesn't seem very safe. Although it seems reasonable, I haven't found any documentation that guarantees it, and if it were guaranteed it seems like the function should be declared as returning `ByteBuffer`.

What is the correct way (preferably supported by documentation) of using the `Buffer` returned by `glMapBufferRange()`?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As you already found, the documentation is lacking. But there is still a fairly conclusive reference: The implementation of the OpenGL Java bindings is part of the public Android source code.

If you look at the implementation of the JNI wrapper for `glMapBufferRange()`, which is in the file [glMapBufferRange.cpp](http://androidxref.com/5.1.0_r1/xref/frameworks/native/opengl/tools/glgen/stubs/gles11/glMapBufferRange.cpp), you can see that the buffer is allocated by calling a function named `NewDirectByteBuffer()`. Based on this, it seems safe to assume that the buffer is indeed a `ByteBuffer`.

While vendors can change the Android code, it seems very unlikely that anybody would change the behavior of the Java bindings (except maybe to fix bugs). If you are concerned that the implementation could change in later Android versions, you can certainly use a standard Java type check:

```
Buffer buf = glMapBufferRange(...);
ByteBuffer byteBuf = null;
if (buf instanceof ByteBuffer) {
    byteBuf = (ByteBuffer)buf;
}
```

Or you could use more elaborate reflection, starting with calling `getClass()` on the returned buffer. The next question is of course what you do if the returned buffer is not a `ByteBuffer`. It's really the only type that makes sense to me.

Comment: +1 for going to the implementation. The implementation could change, however, at least in theory. Is there a way to make practical use of `glMapBufferRange()` without making assumptions on the implementation? Or is this function just incorrectly specified?

Comment: @rhashimoto I added some content. But that part was probably clear to you already.

Comment: I guess most people don't have the option of using ES 3.0+ or do OpenGL via JNI for anything serious. I opened a bounty for more exposure.

Comment: you may want to set `byteBuf.order(ByteOrder.nativeOrder())`, took me awhile to figure out.